# uiTabBar - use for menu NOT view control? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

quick question - I have my "first view" which is going to be the ONLY view in my application. I've added a UITabBar to this view using Interface Builder. I am simply wanting to use this as a menu to control the contents of a scroll view.

For example, the user clicks on the first icon in the UITabBar - I get its tag, then based on that, will add a subview to the scrollview. This is working ok....

...but, I have been viewing a few tutorials on tabbars and it seems that 99% of the time they are used to control views. I simply want it to return my tags.

So my question is this: is what I am doing ok?? Can it be used for simply returning a value rather than changing a view? If this is common/OK practice, how on earth do I reference it?

I can get the selected item tag, but cannot actually reference the uiTabBar to make the first button selected. In my .h file, I tried to specify an IBOutlet for the controller, but I cannot link this in IB.

thanks for any info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To receive notifications that a tab bar item has been clicked you need to modify your view controller to implement the [UITabBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol and add an outlet for the tab bar. To do this, modify your declaration in MyViewController.h to something like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate> {
    UITabBar *tabBar;
    ...
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
```

Then implement the `tabBar:didSelectItem` method in MyViewController.m as follows:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    NSLog(@"Tab clicked: %d", item.tag);
}
```

You **must** also set your view controller as the delegate of the tab bar in IB. (hint: connect up the 'delegate' outlet from the tab bar to File's Owner).

To access the tab bar from your view controller use the `tabBar` property and do things like:

```
self.tabBar.selectedItem = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
```

As to whether this is a good idea - why not? All the tutorials show a tab bar being used with a UITabBarContoller to switch views, but it is designed to operate as a stand-alone control as well. As long as you are not breaking any HIG rules then how you implement your interface switching is up to you.

Comment: worked like a charm - thank you! It was the objectAtIndex which was causing it to fail. I'd also tried the UITabBarDelegate line, but had removed it. 

Thanks very much :)